# How to Create Session in asp .net C# login and registration memberprofile page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP .net C#
i created registration,login and member profile page

after all validations data is stored in database..
and login page also working fine...

i dont know about sessions ..how can i create session and how to make login module more effective using sessions?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Session is Per User basis.
2. You can store the session in SqlServer for to reduce the load on the server

you can create Session like this

```
Session["yourKey"]=someValue;
```

to read this value

```
if(Session["yourKey"]!=null)
{
  //use the Session values. 
}
```

you can use Forms Authentication for Better Approach for login . [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wff0kyh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A session is something the asp.net engine creates for you each time a user logins. This is a good article to start: [Asp.net Session](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Session` is an easy way to transfer values.

You can do something like this:

Create a session variable:

```
Session["name"] = "Any Name";
```

Now, let's make a condition with this variable in another class:

```
if(Session["name"] == "Any Name")
{
    //To do Your Code Here
}
```